# Kubernetes Init Containers pip install

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am not sure I am understanding Kubernetes Init containers properly. What i want to do is run an initialization on the pod so that it pip installs some additional libraries that are not in my app container image. Specifically I am wanting to install the Azure storage queue such that i can use it with the standard TensorFlow image.

I set up my init container with the command "pip install azure-storage-queue" and that ran fine however my app container tells me "No module named azure"

Is this not how an init container can be used?

NOTE: I realize i could create a new image with all my prerequisites installed however this is just for development purposes

Comment: Init containers can do this but you need to mount a volume `pip install` to the mounted volume then mount the volume again in your main app container.
Its not the right use case for init containers however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not really how init containers work... Init containers are meant to initialize the **pod** and the image isn't really shared with other containers that will later run on that pod.

The best solution is to create a new container image including the Python modules you need.

An alternative is to use a command to run in your container that first installs the modules using `pip` and later runs the script that needs them, that way you can avoid creating a new container image.